# How to unblock binary from use because Mac says it is not from identified developer

Tags: terminal, security, install, preferences, binary

I have a binary from work that I'm trying to run. I keep getting an error that

`“my-binary-amd64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.`

I've looked up solutions online and so far I'm encountering problems. [This article](https://macpaw.com/how-to/unidentified-developer-mac) for example suggests navigating to your **Security & Privacy** settings and unlocking the ability to allow changes. I see the prompt for `"my-binary-amd4" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer' and then there is an **Allow Anyway** button but that doesn't do anything. (see image below)

[image: Security & Privacy]

The second suggestion is to find the app on finder and click through some settings. But this is simply a binary, so it doesn't show up in the finder so I can' figure this one out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file `my-binary-amd64` has a `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute. Open a Terminal application window and enter the following command. You need to replace `<path to file>` with the path to the `my-binary-amd64` file.

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine <path to file>/my-binary-amd64
```

This should remove the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute. If you do not have ownership of the `my-binary-amd64` file, then you will need to precede the above command with a `sudo`, as shown below.

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine <path to file>/my-binary-amd64
```

Using `sudo` will require a administrator password.

Comment: I ran into a similar error with [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/). I tried `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/codium` But that didn't release it like it did with the binary. Is there a similar command I could use?

Comment: The solution to the above by the way was `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/VSCodium.app`

Answer (score -1):

For *VSCodium*, open a terminal and run:

```
$ /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```

Or execute:

```
$ codesign --sign - --force --deep /Applications/VSCodium.app
$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/VSCodium.app
```

After this, *VSCodium* can run up via *Spotlight*.

Comment: What does this do exactly? How does it answer the question? Could you please add some more detail?