# Unblock app Mac labels as unidentified developer with xattr

Tags: terminal, security, install, homebrew, preferences

I recently asked how to unblock a binary from Mac's complaint that it's not identified. See [How to unblock binary from use because Mac says it is not from identified developer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436674/how-to-unblock-binary-from-use-because-mac-says-it-is-not-from-identified-develo/436677#436677).

The solution of utilizing the command `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine <path to file>/my-binary-amd64` worked for me.

Now I just used tried to install [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) with `brew install --cask vscodium`. Now when I try to open, I'm getting the same error I was originally getting with the binary...

I tried to adapt the script above to fit my needs: `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/codium` but this didn't work. And it wa simply a guess. Perhaps there's a different path?

There's a solution offered for this problem here: [Software was blocked from opening because it is not from an identified developer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107464/software-was-blocked-from-opening-because-it-is-not-from-an-identified-developer#107523)

But simply clicking the "Open Anyway" button under Security & Privacy only gets me the same refusal prompt from Apple.

I'm hoping that the `xattr` solution can be extended to an application rather than a binary.

Answer (score 3):

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/VsCodium.app` worked for me.

Most likely for other applications initiating the `xattr` command at the parent directory would work for others too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is specifically about homebrew, one thing that might help is the [`--no-quarantine flag`](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-cant-i-open-a-mac-app-from-an-unidentified-developer):

```
brew install --cask --no-quarantine vscodium
```

This disables Apple quarantining for a specific app.